# Java stream collect as a map using streamed element as key and collected list as value?

Tags: java, java-stream, collectors

so I have seen some similar questions to this but have been unable to apply their answers to my code and am wondering how to do this. So basically I have the following code (simplified):

```
public Map<String, List<String>> myFunction(String myApp) {
  List<String> myIds = myService.getIds(myApp);

  return myIds.stream()
      .map(id -> {
          final List<String> myObjects = myService.getListForId(id);
          return new MyWrapper(id, myObjects);
      }).collect(Collectors.toMap(a -> a.ID, a -> a.OBJECTS);
}

class MyWrapper {
    public final String ID;
    public final List<String> OBJECTS;

    public MyWrapper(String id, List<String> objects) {
        ID = id;
        OBJECTS = objects;
    }
}
```

I can't figure out how to access `id` in the Collectors function since the list has no gettable relation to the id so I created a wrapper class to store both values. Any ideas on a way to do this without the wrapper? Thanks

Comment: Did you get the answer you were looking for?

Answer (score 2):

- streams the ids via `myService.getIds`
- then simply maps those `ids` to the list returned by the service (using a method reference).

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = myService.getIds(myApp).
          stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(id->id, myService::getListForId));
```